# Insert a new line in listbox on Matlab GUIDE

Tags: matlab, user-interface, listbox, matlab-guide

I'm building a GUI using GUIDE and I have a listbox where I want to receive several messages after I click in `send_button` but every time I click on the button the message shows in the first line.

```
function send_button_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to send_button (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)  

  % get text
  dstID = get(handles.dest_ID,'String');
  msg = get(handles.message_box,'String');    % message_box = editbox

  % Build message and send
  msg = {['< ', dstID, ' >     ', msg]};      % dstID = number
  set(handles.message_list, 'String', msg);   % message_list = listbox
```

What should I do in order to have something like

```
<3> Message one
<3> Message two
<3> Message three
```

I think this happens because `msg` is a String but I don't know how to insert a `'\n'` or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the cell array of strings containing items of your listbox with `get(handles.message_list,'string')`. Here's a way to solve your problem.

```
function send_button_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to send_button (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)  

% get text
dstID = get(handles.dest_ID,'String');
msg = get(handles.message_box,'String');    % message_box = editbox

%get lisbox cell array of strings
cell_listbox = get(handles.message_list,'string');
%length is needed in order to append the desired message at the end
length_cell_listbox = length(cell_listbox);

% Build message and send
msg = ['< ', dstID, ' >     ', msg];      % dstID = number
cell_listbox{length_cell_listbox + 1} = msg;
set(handles.message_list, 'String', cell_listbox);   % message_list = listbox
```

Using the same idea you can even create a button that deletes the last message stored in your listbox.

Comment: I get this: Error using set. Cell array of strings may only contain string and numeric matrices.

Comment: I edited my answer and removed the braces around the definition of `msg`. Because `{msg = ['< ', dstID, ' >     ', msg]};` is not a string but a cell array of string. Replace it with `msg = ['< ', dstID, ' >     ', msg];` and `msg` will be a string.

Comment: This solved this problem but when I write something longer I can´t see the entire String. And another thing, I have to scroll down to see the last messages. Can I avoid that?

Comment: You can change the font size used in your list box with `set(handles.message_list,'fontsize',8)`. This will shorten the strings in your list box. The problems you mentioned are about the size of your graphical objects. If your first problem was solved you may accept the answer. Feel free to ask another question about any new issue you are encountering.

Comment: I can't change the font size and figure dimensions.

Comment: I didn't find any useful property. I want to have multiple lines when I have a long string and I just have a single line that shows text until my figure dimension.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35367/discussion-between-chocopouce-and-mafap)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
msg=get(handles.message_box,'String');    % message_box = editbox
...
cell_listbox = get(handles.message_list,'string');
...
cell_listbox(end+1)=msg;
```

and if you get an error, please provide in which line it comes up :)

Comment: there is an error in your last line and says "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch."

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append new messages to the top, you need a cell array that starts with your new message. If your messages are too long, reshape them. Note that in the following example, the first line might be too long if `dstID` is greater than 9, you might want to correct `maxlinelength` to account for that.

```
maxlinelength = 25; %// maximum number of characters per line -5
current = get(handles.message_list,'string');

msg = get(handles.message_box,'String');    %// message_box = editbox
rows = ceil(length(msg)/maxlinelength);
msg = [char(8,8,8,8)' '< ' dstID ' > ' msg]; %'// append dstID display
newmsg = cell(1,rows);
for i=1:rows-1 %// for each row
    newmsg{i} = ['    ' a(1:maxlinelength)]; %// store the row in the new cell
    a = a(maxlinelength:end); %// cut off the row from the message
end
newmsg{rows} = ['    ' a]; %// last cell is the rest of msg

new = {msg,current{:}}; %// build new cell aray with msg at the front
set(handles.message_list, 'String', new);   %// message_list = listbox
```

If you want to display a maximum of lines, you can also cut off `new` before setting it as `'String'`:

```
if length(new)>maxlines
    new = new(1:maxlines);
end
```

The line with `char(8,8,8,8)'` puts backspaces in front of `msg` to delete the 4 spaces that will be added later. If you change your newline indentation, change the number of 8's here as well. For example, if you choose to indent by 2 spaces, this becomes `char(8,8)'`.